# fade-in and fade-out transitions while switching between grid/list views

Tags: jquery, css

This is jQuery script for switch between grid and list views to display content. How to give *fade-in* and *fade-out* transitions while switching between grid and list views by adding some strings like this `.fadeOut(1000)` `.fadeIn(1000)`.

***This is the script:***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var $box=jQuery(".post"),
        $bar=jQuery("a.bar_view");
    $dat=jQuery("a.dat_view");
    $dat.click(function () {
        $box.removeClass("bar");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        $bar.removeClass("active");
        jQuery.cookie("dat_style", 0);
        return false
    });
    $bar.click(function () {
        $box.addClass("bar");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        $dat.removeClass("active");
        jQuery.cookie("dat_style", 1);
        return false
    });
    if(jQuery.cookie("dat_style")==0) {
        $box.removeClass( "bar");
        $dat.addClass("active")
    } else {
        $box.addClass("bar");
        $bar.addClass("active")
    }
});
```

***This is (grid/list) HTML Source:***

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
<div class="switch">
<div class="switch-right">
<a class="bar_view" href="#">Grid</a>
<a class="dat_view" href="#">List</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main section" id="main">
<div class="widget Blog" id="Blog1">

<div class="blog-posts hfeed">
<!--Content Start -->
<div class="post bar hentry">
Content
</div>
<div class="post bar hentry">
Content
</div>
<div class="post bar hentry">
Content
</div>
<div class="post bar hentry">
Content
</div>
<!--Content End -->
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I don't want any change to HTML. Thanks :)

*Here is the demo link*: http://bbelog-megagrid.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

See an example. I hope it can be helpful for you. :)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; color:#fff; background-color: #f00;display: none;">List View</div>
<div id="grid" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; color:#000;  background-color: #0f0;">Grid View</div>
<button id="check">View Grid</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#check').click(function(){
        if($('#list').is(':visible')){
            $('#list').fadeOut("fast");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#grid').fadeIn("slow");
                $('#check').text('View List');
            },200);
        }else{
            $('#grid').fadeOut("fast");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#list').fadeIn("slow");
                $('#check').text('View Grid');
            },200);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want any change to HTML, keep this please. `<a class="bar_view" href="#">Grid</a> <a class="dat_view" href="#">List</a>`

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified/optimized version of the answer provided by user3659034.

Key changes:

1. Used fadeOut/fadeIn callbacks. So the next animation is triggered on the completion of animation, not based on a setTimeout duration. Avoid setTimeout when possible in favor of animation completion callbacks.
2. Stored elements as variables so jQuery doesn't have to search the DOM constantly.
3. Removed unnecessary on ready event.

http://jsbin.com/pirileke/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="list" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; color:#fff; background-color: #f00;display: none;">List View</div>
<div id="grid" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; color:#000;  background-color: #0f0;">Grid View</div>
<button id="check">View Grid</button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#check').click(function(){
    var list = $("#list");
    var check = $('#check');
    var grid = $('#grid');

    if(list.is(':visible')){
        list.fadeOut("fast", function() {
            grid.fadeIn("slow");
            check.text('View List');
        });
    } else {
        grid.fadeOut("fast", function() {
            list.fadeIn("slow");
            check.text('View Grid');
        });
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want any change to HTML, keep this please. `<a class="bar_view" href="#">Grid</a>
<a class="dat_view" href="#">List</a>`